# "N" number of parameters using cgi

Tags: perl, cgi

How to retrieve the "N" number of parameters using cgi?

Current I'm using below code. But I don't know the parameters name. That the case how to do that?

Code: **script.cgi**

```
use strict;
use CGI;
my $query = new CGI;
my $paramValue1 = $query->param('name1');
my $paramValue2 = $query->param('name2');
.....
```

Input URL :

```
http://host/cgi-bin/script.cgi?name1=value1&name2=value2&.........
```

Output Value:

```
value1,value2,.....
```

Please help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get all form names,

```
my @names = $query->param;
```

Populating hash by hand,

```
my %param;
$param{$_} = $query->param($_) for $query->param;
```

*update*

```
my @values = map $query->param($_), $query->param;
```

Comment: Is it stores the parameter's value in the array(e-g. value1,value2)?

Comment: @Vasanth for `name1=value1&name2=value2` you want `value1,value2` values in array?

Comment: Your update will put the values of all parameters in `@values`, not just just `name#` parameters. It also won't order them by number. My earlier answer suffers from neither of those problems.

Comment: I'm not sure what continuation of that sentence would lead to a justification that it's reasonable to assume the results should be provided in a different order than the indexes.

Comment: `params()` claim that they take care of the order of names/keys if that is what are you referring to.

Comment: You have something called `name1` and `name2`, and you wonder what order they should be placed in?

Comment: @ikegami order is in which they [came in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999880/n-number-of-parameters-using-cgi/26999907?noredirect=1#comment42530650_26999907)

Comment: Yeah, I know `param` returns them in the wrong order. I already identified that problem with your code.

Comment: @mpapec Is there any way to get the parameter's too?

Comment: @Vasanth names are in `@names` and values are in `@values`

Answer (score 3):

The following is a bad practice:

```
my $name1 = $query->param('name1');
my $name2 = $query->param('name2');
```

Use an array!

```
my @names;
push @names, $query->param('name1');
push @names, $query->param('name2');
```

---

On to your question: How to avoid hardcoding all the indexes, which is especially important since the number of names is variable.

`$query->param` with no arguments returns the list of parameters provided, so it becomes a question of filtering and sorting. You want the following:

```
my @names =
   map { $query->param('name'.$_) }
      sort { $a <=> $b }
         map { /^name(\d+)\z/ ? $1 : () }
            $query->param;
```

---

It would have made more sense if the URL was

```
http://host/cgi-bin/script.cgi?name=value1&name=value2&...
```

Because if you had that URL, you could simply have used

```
my @names = $query->param('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the params into a hash, The shortest/cleanest method would br to use the Vars() method.

```
my $query = CGI->new;
my %param = $query->Vars;
```

Comment: param in scalar context, param in list context, and Vars all treat multivalued parameters differently (e.g. `name1=foo&name1=bar`); which you choose depends on what you want